# Catching a value of None with "or" in an expression

Tags: python, boolean, short-circuiting

I came across this in a code review:

```
def some_method(self, path):
   path = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path or ""))
```

My first reaction was "ahhhh bad!" but on second thought... is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common pattern for implementing some kind of a default value or fallback value if the first part of the expression evaluates to False. Consider it as best-practice - like it or not. It can also be used to turning None into an empty string.

Comment: I see `if x is None: x = defaultValue` more frequently. Exploiting that the logical operators return one of their operands is more commonly used for implementing the conditional operator (`?:`), but that's arguably obsolete since a few versions.

Comment: You always use if...then in any language. But also other language provide kind of shortcuts like the tenary operator in C...and there is a comparable construct in newer Python versions "foo if a else b" as far as I can recall (ugly or not ugly...that's a different topic).

Comment: What other languages support doesn't matter. I'm saying that AFAIK `is x is None: x = default` is much more common *in Python*. Can you confirm that or not?

Comment: I've always used 'path if path is not None else ""'. I wasn't sure if 'path or ""' was a common practice, or just a perl-ism introduced by the dev. I must say that the short-circuit version is growing on me -- it's much shorter than Python's ternary operator. It can behave unintuitively if "path" is something unexpected, like 0, False, or [].

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit pointless in this example though, because calling it like this:

```
instance.some_method()
```

Will yield an error.

You would have to call it like this:

```
instance.some_method(None)
```

It would be better with:

```
def some_method(self, path=None):
   path = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path or ""))
```

Or arguably:

```
def some_method(self, path=""):
   path = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path))
```

...which wouldn't guard against a None value. One can debate whether it's better to whine or "default" in that case.

Anyhow the path can be altogether omitted now:

```
instance.some_method()
```